# Externalize / centralize validation properties in JSF2

Tags: validation, jsf-2

This is an example of an input field in JSF having the validateLength validator.

```
<p:inputText id="priceModelName" size="30"
    value="#{createPriceModelBackingBean.priceModel.priceModelName}"
    required="true" label="#{labelResource.priceModelName}">
    <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="45" />
</p:inputText>
```

The `priceModelName` input field is repeated in another xhtml (create.xhtml and edit.xhtml), i would like to have the values for `minimum` and `maximum` externalized / centralized so that it is not repeated. Is there a good recommendation for such a use case?

I was thinking of probably using a properties file.

```
<f:validateLength minimum="#{validationResource.priceModel.minimum}" maximum="#{validationResource.priceModel.minimum}" />
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem when you try so?

Comment: Hi Balus, didn't hit any problem. But are there any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the way you found out yourself, another ways are:

1. Extend the JSF `LengthValidator` and set the defaults in the constructor.

   ```
   @FacesValidator("priceModelNameLengthValidator")
   public class PriceModelNameLengthValidator extends LengthValidator {

       public PriceModelNameLengthValidator() {
           setMinimum(3);
           setMaximum(45);
       }

   }
   ```

   *(make those magic numbers if necessary constants or configuration settings)*

   and reuse it

   ```
   <f:validator validatorId="priceModelNameLengthValidator" />
   ```

   ---
2. Use JSR 303 bean validation.

   ```
   @Size(min=3, max=45)
   private String priceModelName;
   ```